# Unable to mark SelectListItem as selected (ASP.NET MVC2)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, selected, selectlist

I have a SelectList in my MVC2 model.

In the case that there's only 1 item in the SelectList I want this one item automatically selected (in my view I add an additional item).

My problem is that I can't get this single item to be selected.

So the class behind my model has

```
if (Clients.Count() == 1)
{
     Clients.First().Selected = true;
}
```

But immediately after stepping through this line, if I add a watch to *Clients* I can see that *Selected = null*.

In addition, on my View I have

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Client, Model.Clients, "-- Select Client --") %>
```

When the page loads *-- Select Client --* is always selected.

Can anyone explain how I can get the model to correctly mark the item as being selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model must have a property Model.Client and it would appear (from the code above) that you're not setting that value?

Perhaps in the controller action:

Model.Client = Clients.First();

It's the Model.Client property you need to set though, not the SelectList options.

Comment: In my controller I have

`var jobsWithClients = new JobsWithClients();

jobsWithClients.Client = clientRepository.GetClient(2);

return View(jobsWithClients);`

But that still doesn't mark the one-and-only Client as selected.

Comment: is jobsWithClients.Client a complex type or just a string/int?  The model value for a dropdownlist has always (for me) been used as the selected value.  Could you post your full controller action (GET) and elaborate on the type of jobsWithClients.Client data type please?